# 'full calendar' Remove event-dot on week view only

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

[Full Calendar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV8PN.png)

So i what to remove the event dot before the event text on the week view only. So i want to preserve the event-dot on the day, month and list view.

Is this is possible if so how?

Mind you that i know how to remove the event-dot with CSS:

```
.fc-unthemed .fc-event .fc-content:before, .fc-unthemed .fc-event-dot .fc-content:before{
            content:unset
        }
```

But i want to do this only on week view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find parent class, like .fc-timegrid

```
.fc-timegrid .fc-event-dot .fc-content:before{
            content:unset
        }
```

Always find a class that is unique to that view.